# How to publish flutter app contain api php on Google play

Tags: php, flutter, dart

How to publish flutter app contain api php on Google play

I have a problem when i publish my app on play store because i use php on backend and mysql so when i use api on flutter i call the url from localhost and when i publish my app on play store the app did not work correctelly
I host the file php and database on a free website and when i call the url from dart the problème was (alow access origin) but in php i used headers so a problem com from the website cause he's free or on my méthode?

Comment: allow acces origin header are server problems. try to host your api on a your own server and send the correct headers to the client are allowed to access the server (CORS)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.